# Filling areas that has same number in inkscape

Tags: autofill, inkscape

I want to color all the numbered areas in a picture with a specific color. For example, I want to fill everything marked with number 3 in red. Is this possible?
If I need to provide more details, I'm asking about coloring a picture in the style of "paint by numbers," specifically an SVG file. I want to know if it's possible to do this.

I can select the numbers using the Ctrl+F shortcut to change their individual colors, but what I actually want is to fill the areas where the numbers are located.

This is an example file:
[image]

```
    <path
   data-facetId="212"
   d="m 739.33115,788.04361 q 1.05591,0.75786 2.11182,1.51572 2.37579,-0.50524 4.75159,-1.01048 3.43171,-1.2631 6.86342,-2.52619 3.69568,-0.25262 7.39136,-0.50524 2.90376,-1.2631 5.80751,-2.52619 3.43171,-0.75786 6.86341,-1.51572 3.43171,-0.75786 6.86342,-1.51572 3.4317,-1.01047 6.86341,-2.02095 4.22364,0 8.44728,0 4.22364,0 8.44728,0 4.22364,0 8.44728,0 4.22364,0 8.44728,0 4.22364,0 8.44727,0 3.43171,1.01048 6.86342,2.02095 3.69568,0.50524 7.39137,1.01048 3.4317,0.75786 6.86341,1.51572 3.16773,1.01047 6.33546,2.02095 2.90375,1.2631 5.80751,2.52619 2.90375,1.2631 5.8075,2.5262 2.90375,1.51571 5.8075,3.03143 2.63978,1.26309 5.27955,2.52619 2.63978,1.76833 5.27955,3.53667 2.3758,1.51572 4.7516,3.03143 2.63977,1.76834 5.27955,3.53667 2.37579,1.76833 4.75159,3.53667 2.3758,1.76833 4.75159,3.53667 1.84785,2.27357 3.69569,4.54715 2.11182,2.02095 4.22364,4.0419 2.11182,2.02096 4.22364,4.04191 1.31988,1.76834 2.63977,3.53667 0,0 0,0 0,1.01048 0,2.02096 0.52796,2.52619 1.05591,5.05238 2.11182,2.27357 4.22364,4.54715 1.31989,2.52619 2.63978,5.05238 1.84784,2.52619 3.69568,5.05239 0.79193,3.28405 1.58387,6.5681 1.31988,2.77881 2.63977,5.55762 1.84784,1.76834 3.69568,3.53667 2.11182,2.52619 4.22364,5.05239 1.31989,2.52619 2.63978,5.05238 2.11182,2.02095 4.22364,4.04191 2.11182,2.27357 4.22364,4.54714 1.05591,2.77882 2.11182,5.55763 2.37579,1.76833 4.75159,3.53667 1.58387,2.77881 3.16773,5.55762 1.31989,2.52619 2.63978,5.05239 2.63977,1.26309 5.27954,2.52619 2.3758,2.27357 4.7516,4.54715 0.79193,3.28405 1.58386,6.5681 1.58387,2.27357 3.16773,4.54714 2.63978,1.51572 5.27955,3.03143 1.58387,2.5262 3.16773,5.05239 2.11182,2.02095 4.22364,4.04191 2.11182,2.02095 4.22364,4.0419 1.58387,2.77882 3.16774,5.55763 1.3199,2.77881 2.6398,5.55762 1.8478,2.02096 3.6956,4.04191 1.8479,2.52619 3.6957,5.05238 1.0559,2.77882 2.1119,5.55763 1.8478,2.27357 3.6956,4.54714 1.8479,2.5262 3.6957,5.05239 1.3199,2.77881 2.6398,5.55762 0.7919,3.28405 1.5839,6.5681 2.1118,1.76834 4.2236,3.53667 1.3199,3.03143 2.6398,6.06286 0.5279,3.78929 1.0559,7.57857 0.7919,3.0314 1.5839,6.0629 1.0559,3.0314 2.1118,6.0628 0.7919,3.2841 1.5838,6.5681 0.528,3.7893 1.0559,7.5786 -0.2639,4.0419 -0.5279,8.0838 -0.7919,3.0315 -1.5839,6.0629 -1.0559,3.284 -2.1118,6.5681 0,3.7893 0,7.5786 0,4.0419 0,8.0838 0.264,3.5367 0.528,7.0733 0.7919,2.021 1.5838,4.0419 0,0 0,0 -1.0559,0 -2.1118,0 -1.8478,-0.5052 -3.6957,-1.0104 -2.3758,-1.5158 -4.7516,-3.0315 -2.1118,-2.0209 -4.2236,-4.0419 -2.1118,-2.0209 -4.2237,-4.0419 -2.6397,-1.7683 -5.2795,-3.5367 -3.6957,-0.5052 -7.3914,-1.0104 -3.6957,-0.7579 -7.39134,-1.5158 -4.22364,0 -8.44728,0 -4.22364,0 -8.44728,0 -3.69568,0.7579 -7.39137,1.5158 -3.4317,0.7578 -6.86341,1.5157 -3.16773,1.0105 -6.33546,2.0209 -2.63977,1.7684 -5.27955,3.5367 -2.63977,1.2631 -5.27955,2.5262 -2.63977,1.7683 -5.27955,3.5367 -2.63977,1.2631 -5.27955,2.5262 -2.63977,1.7683 -5.27955,3.5366 -2.37579,1.7684 -4.75159,3.5367 -2.3758,1.5157 -4.75159,3.0314 -2.63978,1.7684 -5.27955,3.5367 -2.90376,1.0105 -5.80751,2.0209 -2.11182,2.2736 -4.22364,4.5472 -2.37579,1.7683 -4.75159,3.5367 -2.90375,1.0104 -5.80751,2.0209 -2.37579,2.021 -4.75159,4.0419 -2.63977,1.2631 -5.27955,2.5262 -2.90375,1.2631 -5.8075,2.5262 -2.90375,1.5157 -5.80751,3.0314 -2.37579,1.5158 -4.75159,3.0315 -3.16773,1.2631 -6.33546,2.5262 -2.63978,1.0104 -5.27955,2.0209 -4.22364,0 -8.44728,0 -2.63977,-1.0105 -5.27955,-2.0209 -3.16773,-1.2631 -6.33546,-2.5262 -2.11182,-1.7684 -4.22364,-3.5367 -2.37579,-1.7683 -4.75159,-3.5367 -2.90375,-1.5157 -5.8075,-3.0314 -2.11182,-1.7683 -4.22364,-3.5367 -2.63978,-1.5157 -5.27955,-3.0314 -2.63978,-1.7683 -5.27955,-3.5367 -2.11182,-1.7683 -4.22364,-3.5366 -2.63978,-1.5158 -5.27955,-3.0315 -2.3758,-2.0209 -4.7516,-4.0419 -2.90375,-1.0105 -5.8075,-2.0209 -2.3758,-2.021 -4.75159,-4.0419 -2.63978,-1.2631 -5.27955,-2.5262 -2.3758,-1.7684 -4.7516,-3.5367 -2.37579,-2.021 -4.75159,-4.0419 -2.3758,-1.5157 -4.7516,-3.0314 -2.63977,-1.5158 -5.27955,-3.0315 -2.37579,-2.0209 -4.75159,-4.0419 -2.3758,-1.5157 -4.75159,-3.0314 -2.3758,-1.7683 -4.7516,-3.5367 -2.63977,-1.7683 -5.27955,-3.5366 -2.3758,-1.5158 -4.75159,-3.0315 -2.11182,-2.0209 -4.22364,-4.0419 -2.11182,-2.0209 -4.22364,-4.0419 -2.3758,-1.7683 -4.7516,-3.5367 -2.37579,-1.7683 -4.75159,-3.5366 -2.11182,-2.021 -4.22364,-4.0419 -2.11182,-2.021 -4.22364,-4.0419 -2.11182,-2.021 -4.22364,-4.042 -2.11182,-2.0209 -4.22364,-4.0419 -2.11182,-2.0209 -4.22364,-4.0419 -1.84784,-2.2735 -3.69568,-4.5471 -1.31989,-2.5262 -2.63978,-5.0524 -1.84784,-2.5262 -3.69568,-5.05239 -2.3758,-1.76833 -4.75159,-3.53667 -2.11182,-2.02095 -4.22364,-4.04191 -1.58387,-2.52619 -3.16773,-5.05238 -2.11182,-2.02095 -4.22364,-4.04191 -1.58387,-2.27357 -3.16773,-4.54715 -1.58387,-2.52619 -3.16773,-5.05238 -1.58387,-2.77881 -3.16773,-5.55762 -1.31989,-2.5262 -2.63978,-5.05239 -0.26397,-3.53667 -0.52795,-7.07334 0,-4.04191 0,-8.08381 0,-3.78929 0,-7.57858 1.58386,-2.27357 3.16773,-4.54715 2.11182,-2.02095 4.22364,-4.04191 2.11182,-2.02095 4.22364,-4.0419 1.84784,-2.27358 3.69568,-4.54715 2.3758,-1.76834 4.7516,-3.53667 2.11182,-2.02095 4.22364,-4.04191 2.37579,-1.76833 4.75159,-3.53667 1.84784,-2.27357 3.69568,-4.54714 2.3758,-1.76834 4.7516,-3.53667 1.84784,-2.5262 3.69568,-5.05239 1.84785,-2.02095 3.69569,-4.04191 1.58386,-2.52619 3.16773,-5.05238 0.79193,-3.03143 1.58386,-6.06286 -1.58386,-2.77882 -3.16773,-5.55763 -1.84784,-2.02095 -3.69568,-4.0419 -1.84784,-2.5262 -3.69569,-5.05239 -1.58386,-2.52619 -3.16773,-5.05239 -2.63977,-1.51571 -5.27955,-3.03143 -2.11182,-2.02095 -4.22363,-4.0419 -2.63978,-1.76834 -5.27955,-3.53667 -2.11182,-1.76834 -4.22364,-3.53667 -2.11182,-3.03143 -4.22364,-6.06286 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0.52795,-1.51572 1.05591,-3.03144 2.11182,-2.02095 4.22364,-4.0419 2.63977,-3.53667 5.27955,-7.07334 0,0 0,0 -1.05591,0 -2.11182,0 2.11182,-1.2631 4.22364,-2.5262 2.63977,-1.26309 5.27954,-2.52619 2.63978,-1.76833 5.27955,-3.53667 2.11182,-1.76833 4.22364,-3.53667 1.84785,-2.27357 3.69569,-4.54714 2.37579,-1.76834 4.75159,-3.53667 2.90375,-1.51572 5.80751,-3.03143 2.11182,-1.76834 4.22364,-3.53667 2.90375,-1.2631 5.8075,-2.5262 2.3758,-2.02095 4.75159,-4.0419 2.63978,-1.2631 5.27955,-2.5262 1.84785,-1.26309 3.69569,-2.52619 1.05591,0 2.11182,0 z"
   style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1"
   id="path1690" />
<g
   class="label"
   transform="matrix(2.1118197,0,0,2.020954,781.01494,901.00399)"
   id="g1696">
  <svg
     width="46.554596"
     height="46.554596"
     overflow="visible"
     viewBox="-50 -50 100 100"
     preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid"
     version="1.1"
     id="svg1694">
    <text
       font-family="Tahoma"
       font-size="50px"
       dominant-baseline="middle"
       text-anchor="middle"
       fill="#000000"
       id="text1692">2</text>
  </svg>
</g>
```

Comment: It depends on your svg. So please add a sample svg (you can reduce it to just a couple of shapes). You could do this e.g with javaScript by checking the text elements positions and retrieve shape-in-point intersections via [`elementsFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint). See related question ["Manipulating an SVG file from Illustrator to change Path names to text within that path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75108452/manipulating-an-svg-file-from-illustrator-to-change-path-names-to-text-within-th/75112810#75112810)

Comment: I added an example image.

Comment: We need to see the svg code

Comment: Until you mentioned it, I didn't know that I could obtain XML code from Inkscape. I have added the XML code for the area with the large number 2 in the middle of the image. I hope I haven't made any mistakes.

Comment: You can save also your svg in inkscape via "optimized svg" export option and open the file in a code/text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in inkscape.
However, you could write a **javaScript helper** to apply color fills according to the label values.

### How it works

- query all `<text>` elements in the svg
- get their center coordinates by [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)
- find intersecting `<path>` elements using [`document.elementsFromPoint(x, y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint)
- apply fill colors as defined in a color array:

```
    const colorFills = [
      'green',
      'red',
      'orange'
    ]
```

E.g paths under a label with a text content of "2" will be mapped to the 2. array value "red".

```js
/**
 * define colorfills for label numbers:
 * label text "1" = green, "2" = red etc.
 */
const colorFills = [
  'green',
  'red',
  'orange'
]

const svg = document.querySelector('svg')
addLabelClasses(svg);


function addLabelClasses(svg) {
  let texts = svg.querySelectorAll("text");
  let shapes = svg.querySelectorAll("path, polygon");

  // shapes must have a fill color - otherwise we can't find intersections
  shapes.forEach((el) => {
    el.style.fill = '#fff'
  });

  //console.log(paths)
  texts.forEach((text) => {
    // find center in screen units
    let {
      x,
      y,
      width,
      height
    } = text.getBoundingClientRect();
    let cx = x + width / 2;
    let cy = y + height / 2;

    // get elements in this point
    let elsUnder = document.elementsFromPoint(x, y)
    // filter paths and polygons
    let shapeUnderLabel = elsUnder.filter(el => {
      return el.nodeName === 'path' || el.nodeName === 'polygon'
    })[0];
    if (shapeUnderLabel) {
      // get color index from text content
      let colorIndex = parseInt(text.textContent) - 1;
      // apply fill
      shapeUnderLabel.style.fill = colorFills[colorIndex] ? colorFills[colorIndex] : '#ccc';
    }
  });

  // show output
  svgOut.value = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg)


}
```

```css
svg{
height:90vmin;
width:auto;
}


textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20em;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path d="M26.88,7.872c-10.985,4.19-13.363,9.06-13.363,9.06l-3.058,14.043
        l1.133,23.103L31.07,69.027l31.257,7.475l25.708-8.607l5.775-23.782L81.354,15.573c0,0-12.006-8.833-12.798-8.833
        S43.301,7.759,42.961,7.985S26.88,7.872,26.88,7.872z"/>
    <path d="M47.944,26.105L36.167,36.751l8.947,16.534l15.289,8.721
        l9.286-9.739c0,0-4.982-11.439-5.436-11.439s-6.003-12.91-6.003-12.91L47.944,26.105z"/>
    <polygon points="80.334,7.532 70.821,15.799 71.84,31.202 81.807,40.941 
        93.811,31.088 94.604,19.084     "/>
    <polygon points="19.745,44.056 5.136,56.796 11.478,75.029 28.805,78.2 
        42.169,66.196 30.73,50  "/>

    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 18.3096 65.542)" font-size="12">2</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 79.6348 27.1499)" font-size="12">2</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 49.8491 47.082)" font-size="12">3</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 24.1987 26.1304)" font-size="12">1</text>
</svg>

<h3>SVG output</h3>
<textarea id="svgOut"></textarea>
```

For testing: [codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/oNQaBoy)